# Swap all website urls to embed via preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, filter, preg-replace

I am tryin to replace url in my code with another piece of text.

I have urls like this

```
http://example.com/id/16028
```

I need to replace all these with `<h2>Not Allowed</h2>` in my filters code it looks like this.

```
<a href="http://example.com/id/16028" rel="nofollow">http://example.com/id/16028</a>
```

So this text

```
Hello here is my link <a href="http://example.com/id/16028" rel="nofollow">http://example.com/id/16028</a>
```

Would look like this

```
Hello here is my link <h2>Not Allowed</h2>
```

I am really bad at regex here is what i have so far

```
function custom_filter($content){
    $rules = array(
        '#<a href="http://(www\.)?example\.com/([^ ?\n/]+)((\?|/).*?(\n|\s))?" rel="nofollow">http://(www\.)?example\.com/([^ ?\n/]+)((\?|/).*?(\n|\s))?</a>#i' => '<h2>Not Allowed</h2>',
        '#<a (?:.*?)href=["\\\']href=["\\\']http[s]?:\/\/(?:[^\.]+\.)*example\.com\/id\/([^ ?\n/]+)((\?|/).*?(\n|\s))["\\\']#ixs' => '<h2>Not Allowed</h2>'

    );

    foreach ($rules as $link => $player)
        $content = preg_replace($link, $player, $content);


    return $content;

}
```

Please help

I am almost there with this function but i am still getting the urls as well as the change text.

```
function change_tags($content = ''){
    preg_match_all("/example.com\/id\/([1-9.-_]+)/", $content, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
         $content .= '<h2>Not Allowed</h2>';
    }   
    return $content;

}
```

Comment: You're not making any changes to `$content`. Replace `$content = preg_replace(...);` with `$string = preg_replace(...);` and see if that helps.

Comment: sorry updated that was just me copy and pasting

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like the below. I am guessing you are trying to stop some spam.

```
$spam = 'Your Spam';
$spam = preg_replace( '~<a.+?href="http:\/\/example\.com\/id\/[0-9]+"[^>]*?>[^<]*?<\/a>~is', '<h2>Not allowed</h2>', $spam );
```

This will allow for some diversification in the spam. You could also do a specific domain:

```
$spam = 'Your Spam';
$spam = preg_replace( '~<a.+?href="http:\/\/(?:www.)?example\.com[^"]*?"[^>]*?>[^<]*?<\/a>~is', '<h2>Not allowed</h2>', $spam );
```